# Sharepoint 2013 WPD Getting substring not working

Tags: workflow

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here
I have setup the workflow to copy 5 characters from these strings. I know the strings have data, because I'm logging that out as well.  But, I'm getting nothing from the substring copy. What am I doing wrong?

WPD Steps

[image: WPD Image]

Output Log

[image: Workflow Log]

Comment: Is workflow completes or get suspended?

Comment: It completes successfully

Comment: try using the SET command - get the workflow to copy the substring to a new text field.  Does it copy anything?

Answer (score 0):

I might be barking up the wrong tree, but here goes...  Do the values relate to the status of another workflow?  If so, does the column display the status of the workflow e.g. 'In Progress' or 'Complete'?

For instance, my workflow shows a value of 'Completed'.

[image]

However...if I press F12 to view in developer mode I see that the way Sharepoint views it, the value is actually '5'.  The label 'Completed' is only shown for us mere mortal humans.

[image]

As I said, this is probably a long-shot answer.

Comment: No the fields it is reading from , and copying from, are just regular strings.

Comment: did you define the NewGate OldGate fields yourself?  What do you see if you use F12 and select the view icon I indicated in my answer?  What does it say the value is?

Comment: They are not fields. They are workflow variables that are stored as strings.